# VB.NET Txtfile -> SQL server loop issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So, I am trying to read in a text file using VB.NET and add the values of each line into a SQL Server database table. The code I have this far reads in the first line but keeps trying to read in the same line and fails. It adds the first, but like I stated it fails after the first one. I am quite sure the problem is in my loop and/or mysplit() array values. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
Public Sub addTxtMember()
    'Dim fileName As String
    ' fileName = Application.StartupPath + "c:\users\james needham\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\textfiletutorial1\textfiletutorial1\textfile1.txt"
    Dim fileName As Integer = FreeFile()

    'If File.Exists(fileName) Then
    'Dim iofile As New StreamReader(fileName)
    FileOpen(fileName, "TextFile1.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    Dim ioline As String
    'Dim iolines() As String
    Dim eID, fName, lName, email, phone
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ioline = LineInput(fileName)

    'Do Until EOF(fileName)
    While Not ioline = ""
        ' Dim endsplit = Split(ioline, "")
        Dim mysplit = Split(ioline, ",")

        eID = mysplit(0)
        fName = mysplit(1)
        lName = mysplit(2)
        phone = mysplit(3)
        email = mysplit(4)

        ' try
        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO Employees1 (eID, fName, lName, phone, email) " & _
                                 "VALUES (" & _
                                 "'" & eID & "'," & _
                                 "'" & fName & "', " & _
                                 "'" & lName & "', " & _
                                 "'" & phone & "', " & _
                                 "'" & email & "')"

        'MsgBox(strInsert)

        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)

        'has to be non when inserting, updating, or deleting
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLCon.Close()

        ' Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'End Try

    End While
    FileClose(fileName)
    'Else
    'MsgBox("fILE NOT FOUND")
    ' FileClose(fileName)
    'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You never re-read the line in your loop.

Comment: you arent reading anything from the file into `ioline`.  You also need to learn about SQL Parameters

Comment: now is your chance you are just starting out, DON'T USE `i` AS A VARIABLE NAME!

Comment: Voting to close as Typo as the answer is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Have you ever even attempted to run this in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, I have ran it in the debugger and it adds the first line of the text file to the sql server database but then keeps trying to add the same one. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

The following comment in no way implies I believe this program will work -- it is has many errors but to answer your question about only seeing one line show up:

add the line

```
ioline = LineInput(fileName)
```

before the

```
END WHILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a nudge regarding your loop...

```
    For Each line As String In (New StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")).ReadToEnd.Split(ControlChars.CrLf)
        'examine the value of line and parse it into the DB here
    Next
```